# How to use Google Places API- Events in a android application

Tags: android, google-places-api

for my 2 nd year project I am hoping to create an GPS application which can add and delete events using Events in Google Places API but I dont know how to start using the API and proceed. Please help me on this

Comment: have a look at this tutorial this will help you. http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting here https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/